# How to install WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle on Symfony 2.0.x

Tags: symfony, pagination, doctrine-orm

So far, the bundles I've used for Symfony2 has been installed modifying the `deps` file and then running the command `bin/vendors install`, but for this bundle ([WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle)) the installation process is made using `git submodule add` command which I don't fully understand.

```
git submodule add http://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta.git vendor/pagerfanta
git submodule add http://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle.git vendor/bundles/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaBundle
```

I assume that this command retrieves the master version of both libraries, but the documentation says that if I'm using Symfony 2.0.x (which is my case) I should get the symfony2.0 branch:

"**Note:** If you are using a 2.0.x release of Symfony2, please use the symfony2.0 branch of this bundle. The master branch of this bundle tracks the Symfony2 master branch."

How should I modify the git commands to get the symfony2.0 branch instead of the master? Why some bundles are installed using the deps files while others uses git submodules? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use bin/vendors and the deps system to install these bundles/vendors

in **deps**

```
[Pagerfanta]
    git=http://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta.git
    target=/pagerfanta

[WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle]
    git=http://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle.git
    target=/bundles/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaBundle
    version=origin/symfony2.0
```

And re-run `bin/vendors install`